# Heroku Provision Apps programmatically

Tags: heroku

I want to achieve a setup similar to [Heroku Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) without using Github. We use Bitbucket and the build-in Pipelines feature.

The target solution should look as follows: Depending on our Bitbucket Pipeline config, we would use PR creation or a manual build step to provision a Heroku app. The latter part is the one I am inquiring about: Is it possible to automatically provision an app from a template/recipe?

I stumbled upon [Heroku Buttons](https://github.com/heroku/button-sample). Is this similar to Ansible Playbooks and aids in fully automating the provisioning of Heroku apps?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial on how to provision your Heroku infrastructure with Terraform. Link to tutorial: [provisioning-your-infrastructure-as-code-with-heroku-terraform](https://medium.com/profitchimp/provisioning-your-infrastructure-as-code-with-heroku-terraform-c5af0d6db901)

In response to `"Is it possible to automatically provision an app from a template/recipe"`, when you write your terraform code, you are building out your own template/recipe that can be re-used by spinning up or tearing down your infrastructure with a single command.

If you're curious about why you might want to use Terraform, check out [this](https://medium.com/profitchimp/6-simple-reasons-why-you-should-have-started-using-terraform-like-yesterday-3982b5e0292) article.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is offering [support for Heroku](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/heroku/index.html). I'll go ahead and try that out.